# Socket hang up error from GitHub API using Node HTTP request

Tags: node.js, http, github

I'm making the following request:

```
var options = {
    host: "api.github.com",
    port: 443,
    path: "/repos/myusername/myreponame/issues",
    headers: {Authorization: "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64")}
};

var request = http.get(options, function(response) {
    response.on("data", function(data) {
        console.log("data");
    });
});

request.on("error", function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

This results in an error:

```
{ [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured this one out. I was using `http` instead of `https`. Here's the working code:

```
var https = require("https");

username = "myusername";
password = "mypassword";

var options = {
    host: "api.github.com",
    port: 443,
    path: "/repos/myusername/myreponame/issues",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64"),
        "User-Agent": username
    }
};

var request = https.get(options, function(response) {
    response.on("data", function(data) {
        process.stdout.write(data);
    });
});

request.on("error", function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I made the exact same mistake. This helped immensely.